# how to get the parameter of a link in google script

Tags: php, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to receive a parameter that happened to me in a link.

I program in PHP, and as I receive a parameter it is as follows:

`localhost/example/page1.php?lenguaje=espanol`

```
<?php
    $value=$_GET['lenguaje'];
    echo $value;
?>
```

In google script I have the following:

**Index.html**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br>
        <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Trabajos&inci=INC00000237379'> <input type='button' name='button' value='Index.html'></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Codigo.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {

    Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
    if(!e.parameter.page){
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
    }

    var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page)
    template.action=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    return template.evaluate();

}

function getScriptUrl(){
    var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    return url
}
```

from `Index.html` get the following link, and at the same time I am passing the parameter to the `Trabajos.html` page

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwQ4zJDadgasjdgag1dasdwertdafa-hncX1kEexNQmbkASUVdaQ/exec?page=Trabajos&inci=INC00000237379

but on the `Trabajos.html` sheet I don't know how to receive the parameter.

How could I receive it? is that I need to receive that parameter to be able to consult my page `Codigo.gs`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You show an example with a link to your page, but what does that have to do with a link to google? Please clarify what you're trying to do (explain from start to finish), show the expected result, your attempt and what you're currently getting.

Comment: Edit the question, I hope you understand what I'm looking for

Comment: do you want to get this parameter through javascript/jquery ?

Comment: I want to get this parameter on my Trabajos.html page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the query parameters of `page=Trabajos&inci=INC00000237379` at the HTML of `Trabajos.html`, when `Index.html` button is clicked.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, the query parameters of `page=Trabajos&inci=INC00000237379` are retrieved with `google.script.url`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows. In your case, please modify `Trabajos.html`. But in your question, `Trabajos.html` is not provided. So I show you the Javascript for retrieving the query parameters. Please add the following Javascript to `Trabajos.html`.

```
<script>
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  console.log(location.parameters);
});
</script>
```

#### Result:

When `Index.html` button is clicked (The link is like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?page=Trabajos&inci=INC00000237379`) and `Trabajos.html` page is opened, the following value can be seen at the console.

```
{
  "page": [
    "Trabajos"
  ],
  "inci": [
    "INC00000237379"
  ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to put the retrieved query parameter to `value` of the input tag.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please use the following script as `Trabajos.html`.

```
<input id="target">
<script>
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  document.getElementById("target").value = location.parameters.inci;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(location.parameters));
});
</script>
```

- If you want to put `page`, please modify `location.parameters.inci` to `location.parameters.page`.

Comment: how to display that parameter in an <input >?

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your replying, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `display that parameter in an <input >`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you very much @tanaike , it's a problem I had several weeks ago and you solved it

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.