# How to Fetch URL Parameters from a Google Script Web URL

Tags: html, google-apps-script, url-parameters

Team,

I am trying to fetch URL Parameters from Google Script Web URL
Please help
https://script.google.com/a/------------/exec?x=100555683

I am unable to fetch parameter x and its value 10555683 on load of HTML page

Comment: I thought that in your question, this thread might be the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58552316

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What solution did you find?

Answer (score 0):

when html onload you can call this service:

```
    <script>
        google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
         const value = location.parameters["x']
         console.log(location.parameters);
         console.log(location.hash);
        });
   </script>
```

or in sever side, the doGet(e) function:

```
function doGet(e){
  const x = e.parameter["x"];
}
```

You will get the value of x.